# save form data with one to one relationship in django

Tags: python, django

I have one to one relationship with the Django User model and custom Profile model. I trying to save user and profile data at the same time when the user is registered. But the problem is the data of the profile model is not validating and data is not saving in the database
here is code

model.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'profile_pictures')
    Join_as = models.CharField(choices=USER_CHOICES, max_length=70)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

form.py

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['picture','Join_as']
        labels = {
            'picture':'Upload Profile Picture'
        }
        widgets = {
            'Join_as':forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-select'}),
            }
```

view.py

```
def rigister(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        user_form = UserCreationForm()
        profile_form = ProfileForm()
    contaxt = {'user_form':user_form,'profile_form':profile_form}
    return render(request, 'registration/register.html', contaxt)
```

register.html

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row row-cols-2">
        {% for user in user_form  %}
        <div class="col">
            {{user.label_tag}} {{user}} {{user.errors|striptags}}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
        {% for profile in profile_form %}
        <div class="col">
            {{profile.label_tag}} {{profile}} {{profile|striptags}}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-success">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wor with the object saved by the `user_form` as `.user` of the instance wrapped in the `profile_form`:

```
def rigister(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            profile_form.instance.user = user
            profile_form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        user_form = UserCreationForm()
        profile_form = ProfileForm()
    contaxt = {'user_form':user_form,'profile_form':profile_form}
    return render(request, 'registration/register.html', contaxt)
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: @KamranKhan: likely that is beause one of the forms contains invalid data, you should *only* redirect when the POST request was successful.

Comment: @KamranKhan: can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66723586/67579) the question and add the HTML form? Likely you did not specify the correct encoding type.

Comment: @ willem Van Onsem i have edited question

Comment: @KamranKhan: if you only redirect in the `if user_form.is_valid() ...` block (see edit) then normally the form should render what is not validated.